# InApp Purchase Clarification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app and I want to know if I have to use InApp purchase to have add-ons for the app? I have different characters that I want my users to be able to download, some are free and some are pay.  So here are my questions:

1) I could not see any way to offer something using InApp purchase for free, so I am assuming I need to use InApp for Pay characters and do it myself for free characters.  Is that correct?

2) Since I am responsible for downloading my characters, is there an approved way of doing this, can I just use dataWithContentsFromURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I could not see any way to offer something using InApp purchase for
>   free, so I am assuming I need to use InApp for Pay characters and do
>   it myself for free characters. Is that correct?

Yes

> 2) Either way I do it, am I responsible for downloading the content
>   (characters) myself after the InApp Purchase verification, or free
>   selection?

Yes, you will have to provide some download mechanism

> 3) If I am responsible for downloading my characters, is there an
>   approved way of doing this? Is it just using dataWithContentsFromURL?

Yes, or you could use some helper classes such as http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
They have a good class for download stuff that has download resume functionality
Such as http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_download_cache

In all ways, you will have to provide server side api, and url for implementing the download process

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.  ASIHTTPRequest is not really supported anymore, do you know of any other classes that can be used to download from the server. Or is it best to just write my own?

Comment: Why not supported, i use it everyday in all the projects i do? do you mean because of ARC?

Comment: When I looked at the link and read about it, there was a he dining on the page that says he no longer works on it and suggest using something else.  I am not too concerned about ARC.  I guess you seem to like it, is it easy to use?

Comment: mmmm i use it in all my projects, and i have more than 10, so yes i find it easy to use and very extensive

Comment: Do you have a free app that uses it?  I would love to take a quick look and see what it looks like to the user?  I love the idea of providing a progress bar of the download.  If not, i will download the  code and give it a try.

Comment: Yes i do and it has in-app purchase and a download server http://itunes.apple.com/sa/app/mktbt-nwn/id432087846?mt=8, also please dont forget to upvote or/and accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: LOL, yes, I will definitely up vote as you were very helpful.

Comment: Please be advised the app is in arabic language :P

Comment: LOL, yes, that is what I was laughing at.... I hope I can figure out how to view a download as I cannot read it!!!

Comment: No No its ok the language inside the application is english :P

Comment: Yes, I saw that... very nice app!!  Is there a free book that I can choose to see a download?  Do you show any progress whilst it downloads?  I will play with it, I registered, and I will take a look at the code,  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yes there are but how can i give you there names now :D, and also yes i saw a download progress, ASI gives you a progress delegate, i really like these classes i suggest that you play around them alilttle :)

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends if you really need to download characters from an outside (your) server or you can just keep them in the final application.

You must provide a common way to download character and take care of using InApp purchase just for paid ones. When you are going to use the `StoreKit` you will have some methods to call which will result in callbacks called from the Apple transaction manager that will be able to notify if a purchase ended well or whatever.

Then it depends if you are going to make in-app purchases downloadable from a server or just unlockable:

- for built-in content you will just enable it
- for downloadable content you will receive a transaction receipt that will be sent to your server to check the validity of the transactions

Both models are described in detail [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1).

Comment: Yes, i have read through that so I get it.  I just need to figure out the best way to download my characters.  I could roll my own, or look for a class that I could use.  My content could be large, so downloading with a progress bar of some sort would be nice.  No of any, or should i just roll my own?